# csharp mysql compile error CS0246 under powershell

Tags: c#, mysql

I am attempting to compile a simple C# program to do a select on one of the tables in the MySQL database on my windows 10 laptop. When I attempt to compile the code under Developer PowerShell for VS 2019 using the following command:

csc mysql1.cs

I get the error message error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found

I checked under the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.18\Assemblies\v4.5.2 and I did indeed have the file MySql.Data.dll

All the articles I found with google stated that I had to "add a reference" to my project. I do not have a project, this is just a command line compile.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a MySQL Test");
        string mysql_info = "Persist Security Info=False;server=localhost;database=myschema;uid=root;password=mypassword";

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection dbConn =
    new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(mysql_info);
MySqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT user_id from hockey_users WHERE username ='someone'";

try
{
    dbConn.Open();                
} catch (Exception erro) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + erro);
    this.Close();
}

MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    idnumber = reader.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("id = " + idnumber);
}

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: according to the header displayed when I run a command line compile the compiler I am using is : Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.3752.0 for C# 5

Comment: I tried adding a "/reference" option to my compile command

but I received a number of new error messages:
error CS0103: The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current 
error CS0026: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method or static field initializer

Comment: You are usinng it like in visual studio but in csc you have to add references  see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option

Comment: I tried adding a "/reference" option to the compile command but that caused different errors to occur (see my previous comment)

Comment: i reran the visual studio community installer to upgrade to the most recent version. I also asked for extra stuff for the C# compiler (the name Rosyln was listed ?) I am still seeing the same error messages

Comment: your error is because of  MessageBox.Show("Error" + erro);  like i said you are using code like in visual studio. replace it.

Comment: thanks for all your help. my code now compiles properly. The execution results are not correct so I have more debugging to do.